# Split xml from nth element to xth element

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

Below is my XML structure  :

```
<cars>  
  <car>  
    <ford color="black" >eco sport</ford>    
    <maruti color="red" >zen</maruti>  
    <hyundai color="blue" >accent</hyundai>  
  </car>  
  <car>  
    <ford color="green" >figo</ford >    
    <maruti color="red" >swift</maruti>  
    <hyundai color="white" >santro</hyundai>  
  </car> 
  <car>  
    <ford color="red" >aaa</ford >    
    <maruti color="red" >bbb</maruti>  
    <hyundai color="red" >ccc</hyundai>  
  <car>  
  </car>
    <ford color="white" >ddd</ford >    
    <maruti color="white" >eee</maruti>  
    <hyundai color="white" >fff</hyundai>  
  </car>
</cars>
```

From Above XML structure, I need to have a parser in java which will split the xml and return only one xml with only 2 or 3 elements(like from 1-2 or 2-3 or 2-4) as I will specify the element row dynamically. So if I pass params in a method `splitXML(2,3)`, my returned new xml should be like:

```
<cars>  
    <car>  
      <ford color="green" >figo</ford >    
      <maruti color="red" >swift</maruti>  
      <hyundai color="white" >santro</hyundai>  
    </car> 
    <car>  
      <ford color="red" >aaa</ford >    
      <maruti color="red" >bbb</maruti>  
      <hyundai color="red" >ccc</hyundai>  
    </car>  
</cars>
```

Could some body please help me?

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0 you could use `subsequence()`. (I know the question is tagged 1.0, but maybe this will help a future visitor.)

**XML Input**

```
<cars>  
    <car>  
        <ford color="black" >eco sport</ford>    
        <maruti color="red" >zen</maruti>  
        <hyundai color="blue" >accent</hyundai>  
    </car>  
    <car>  
        <ford color="green" >figo</ford >    
        <maruti color="red" >swift</maruti>  
        <hyundai color="white" >santro</hyundai>  
    </car> 
    <car>  
        <ford color="red" >aaa</ford >    
        <maruti color="red" >bbb</maruti>  
        <hyundai color="red" >ccc</hyundai>  
    </car>  
    <car>
        <ford color="white">ddd</ford>
        <maruti color="white">eee</maruti>
        <hyundai color="white">fff</hyundai>
    </car>
</cars>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="start" select="2"/>
    <xsl:param name="end" select="3"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cars">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|subsequence(car,$start,($end - $start)+1)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<cars>
   <car>
      <ford color="green">figo</ford>
      <maruti color="red">swift</maruti>
      <hyundai color="white">santro</hyundai>
   </car>
   <car>
      <ford color="red">aaa</ford>
      <maruti color="red">bbb</maruti>
      <hyundai color="red">ccc</hyundai>
   </car>
</cars>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use xslt based on [Identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) into which you can pass parameters with desired range (the way how can be done depend on xslt processor you use). XSLT could look like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <!-- Take a start and end position to be output as a parameters from outside-->
    <xsl:param name="startPosition"  />
    <xsl:param name="endPosition"  />

    <!-- Use "Identity transform" -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- When you are processing car element... -->
    <xsl:template match="car">
        <!-- ... take a look at its position. Copy it only if its position is in the desired range -->
        <xsl:if test="not((position() &lt; $startPosition) or (position() &gt; $endPosition))">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With values startPosition = 2 and endPosition = 3 you would obtain following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cars>
    <car>
        <ford color="green">figo</ford>
        <maruti color="red">swift</maruti>
        <hyundai color="white">santro</hyundai>
    </car>
    <car>
        <ford color="red">aaa</ford>
        <maruti color="red">bbb</maruti>
        <hyundai color="red">ccc</hyundai>
    </car>
</cars>
```

It is just a concept. In real you should check some constraints of parameter like if they are numbers, if endPosition isn't lower than startPosition etc.

Comment: I think you would need `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` or `<xsl:strip-space elements="cars"/>` to have `position()` work as intended, unless you use an XML parser like MSXML which strips white space by default.

Comment: I tried with Altova and it worked. But yes, you're right, the solution will be more robust with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need an XML parser. There are plenty of resources on the web. This is a [simple tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/) about reading and manipulating XML.